# how to print province name using province_id in laravel 5.6

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am developing app using laravel 5.6. in my application I have three tables as **provinces**,**districts**,**towns** and My models have following relationship with each models,

```
 Province
    public function districts()
            {
                return $this->hasMany(District::class);
            }





 District
        public function province()
            {
                return $this->belongsTo(Province::class);
            }

Town
 public function district()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(District::class);
    }
```

now I have data grab using towns table in Controller,

```
 $town_list = DB::table('towns')

                     ->groupBy('province_id')
                     ->get();
```

and dropdown selection input in blade file,

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Province</label>
        <select name="province_id" id="province_id" class="form-control input dynamic" data-dependent="district_id" >
            <option value="">Select Province</option>
            @foreach($town_list as $town)
            <option value="{{$town->province_id}}">{{$town->province_id}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
        </div>
```

now I can see province_id in My selection input but I need print province name in my selection input,
my table structure,

```
provinces
id    name
1    alabama
2    prodova

districts
id   name    province_id
1     x          1
2     y          2

towns
id   name    district_id    province_id
1     gh          1              1
2     ju          2              2
```

how can do this?

Comment: What if you change `<option value="{{$town->province_id}}">{{$town->province_id}}</option>` to `<option value="{{$town->province_id}}">{{$town->name}}</option>` ?

Comment: in my towns table there is only province_id not name...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use eager loading:

`$towns = Towns::with('district.province')->groupBy('province_id')->get();`

Now you can loop in your view and call the province name.

Comment: In your view looping $towns you use  
    $town->district->province 
and this should work. 

Ps:. I don't use DB::table, it's kind a hard coding, furthermore you can't use eager loading with DB::table (with Query Builder in general), so you should call your model in the controller and use laravel eloquent